# Multiprocessing Queue do not release memory

Tags: python, queue, multiprocessing

When speed of queue.put() is faster than queue.get() speed, I find the P1 process is going to use large memory (because P1 put line from a large text file incessantly). Even P2 has finished getting line from queue subsequently. The memory that was used by P1 don't still release. How to fix this issue? Below is sample and test code.

Thanks!

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

def addline(q):
   f = file('a big text file','r')
   line = True
   while line:
      line = f.readline()
      q.put(line, False)
   f.close()
   print "P1:finished"
   while 1:
      time.sleep(2)

def getline(q):
   f = file('/tmp/bak','w') 
   line = True
   while line:
      line=q.get()
      f.write(line)
      time.sleep(0.01)
   f.close()
   print "p2:finished"



if __name__ == "__main__":
   q = Queue()
   p1 = Process(name="addline", target=addline, args=(q,))
   p2 = Process(name="getline", target=getline, args=(q,))
   p1.start()
   p2.start()
```

**Edit:**
I try to read a text file(44MB) and observe /proc/pid/smaps. I found the memory which hasn't been released become Private_Dirty in heap.

```
00fb3000-04643000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
Size:              55872 kB
Rss:               55844 kB
Pss:               55163 kB
Shared_Clean:          0 kB
Shared_Dirty:       1024 kB
Private_Clean:         0 kB
Private_Dirty:     54820 kB
Referenced:        54972 kB
Swap:                  0 kB
KernelPageSize:        4 kB
MMUPageSize:           4 kB
```

Comment: What are you doing with `while 1: q.get()` in `getline()`?

Comment: In this test case, I just want to keep P2. I've removed it. Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered setting a limit for your Queue? If the reading process can't keep up then without a limit the whole stuff has to be buffered in the Queue.

Comment: Is there any way to clean buffer which has been read? Thanks very much.

Comment: @jess did you get any solution

Comment: @mata In similar case I have found that not setting the `maxsize` parameter in Queue causes a constant memory leak which within some time interval results in consuming of all the available computer memory.

Answer (score 1):

Python's garbage collector deletes an object as soon as it is not referenced anymore. As long as the write rate can keep up with read rate of your storage hardware, reading the content of a file while writing it at the same time from two independent threads/processes must be possible without growing memory and with a small memory footprint. I believe your problem disappears when you use Python's language constructs that are more appropriate for your use case. I'll try to comment on that.

For reading a file line by line you should use the following concept:

```
with open('filepath') as f:
    for line in f:
        do_something_with(line)
```

You do not have to explicitly `.close()` the file then. The same applies to writing the file. Read about the `with` statement here: http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm

From my point of view, for the use case you've presented, a `multiprocessing.Pipe` instead of a `multiprocessing.Queue` would be more appropriate because of the "stream-like" application. It seems odd to represent raw file content as items in a queue. Furthermore, you can get rid of a lot of communication overhead if you'd use threads instead of independent subprocesses (then you should use an `os.pipe` for inter-thread communication)**. In any case, you should `join()` threads and subprocesses after starting them.

** For your use case (copying a file), the global interpreter lock (GIL) will not be a performance problem.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!! In my real case, I have to collect many sources. In order to avoid GIL issue, I use multiprocessing and multiprocessing.Queue. About reading file, I have used generator. After Queue.get, P2 will analysis it, So P2 is slower than P1. And then P1 will use memory and don't release it. I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: If your data analysis is significantly slower than reading the file and you do not wish to have a large buffer (i.e. growing memory usage), there is no other option than implementing a feedback mechanism: the reader needs some indication when to pause reading data.

Comment: In normal circumstances the analyzer is fast enough, so reader don't use memory. But I'm afraid there are some exceptions. And I'm curious  about why the buffer don't release, even reader has gotten data from buffer. Thanks!